# Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, nvme

I booted from a live usb and installed 15.10 but at the end of the installation process, I get an error:

`Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme`.

Next, it gives the option to change where the bootloader is installed but on pressing OK at this point, grub does nothing. I can't find any information regarding /dev/nvme, only /dev/sda which has always been what I've seen doing linux installations in the past. Why is it /dev/nvme now and how do I fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: It's probably also worth noting that I turned off secure boot and switched from UEFI to legacy because the ubuntu installation kept freezing at the purple loading screen on UEFI mode.

Comment: /dev/nvme stands for SSDs

Comment: Ah ok, cool. thanks for clearing that up. Any reason grub wouldn't be able to install on an SSD?

Comment: But its  not read as nvme, gparted should read your ssd as sda

Comment: Boot to your live USB and click on try Ubuntu, then from there open gparted and see what your ssd is read as. Do you have other drives installed too?

Comment: Does anyone know if the new naming nomenclature is supported in legacy boot?

Comment: I'm using the Ubuntu desktop 15.10 live image. Gparted doesn't recognize my nvme disk, it only shows the live USB as /dev/sda1. Gparted is v0.19.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the installer to install Grub to `/dev/nvme0n1` (at least that's how it shows up on my NUC 5i5RYK with an NVMe drive. However, at least in my case, it appears the installer is broken as I still was not be able to boot into the newly installed system.

However, I did find two methods that fix broken Ubuntu 15.10 boot failure after initial install:

1. Use the GUI program [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

   The default or
   "Recommended Repair" doesn't work, but I selected the "Advanced
   Options" and uncheck "SecureBoot" but keep all other default options
   then follow the instructions, the system correctly boots to the
   newly installed OS.

   Results available at
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/14439023/
2. Install Ubuntu 15.04 first, then upgrade to 15.10. As an alternative
   to  running Boot Repair, I found that if I install 15.04, run all
   updates:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   then run

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -d
   ```

   then 15.10 will successfully boot.

Answer (score 12):

None of the suggestions worked but I found the solution for me.

When the installer asks how to partition, choose `Manual`, after that:

1. Select `/dev/nvme0n1`, it will ask if it should create a new partition table(only the first time) - accept that.
2. Select `free space` and choose to create an `EFI boot section`(in different tools this could be called differently but all should say `EFI`), set it to `500 MB`(this should be first, before the other partitions inside `nvme0n1`)
3. Now partition the rest of the `free space`, for example setting all of the `free space` to be root `/`, `ext4`(it is recommended to at least set `/boot` separately).
4. At the bottom you should see a menu that asks where `grub` should be installed. Choose `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Done, it is a very simple setup in reality and you don't need to disable UEFI.

Comment: Thank you very much! EFI boot section was what I was missing. Installation completed successfully right after creating it.

Comment: This did not work for me until I booted the USB stick with the install image in [UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: Bios in Legacy mode and Manual partitions, with default / ext4 and swap partitions (just the two) worked for me.  I get a invalid partition table error on screen just before the Ubuntu log-in GUI, probably from one of the previous failed install attempts.  So I plan on wiping the drive and doing it again.  Might have to dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=1b count=1000 in order to clear the corrupt information.  I have no plans on ever installing Windows so I was trying to avoid creating the EFI data.  Thanks +1  Worked on a Dell E3 Tower 5818

Comment: This allowed it to boot...but the actual install was unusable. Everything was either super slow and/or crashed. I couldn't even get updates because apt-get would dump a trace.

Comment: @Cerin Well, that's another issue.
If you managed to boot, than the instructions were correct.
That you have some kind of hardware or network issue, that's another thing...

Comment: @ctuffli If you don't boot into the UEFI option(USB stick), than it means that you don't want UEFI(in this case you should not follow the answers here).
Obviously, if you want an UEFI install, boot into UEFI and follow these steps...

Comment: I follow this steps but it got stuck on the restart. I believe because I kept the freeDos already there. Should format the partition where it is be a solution?

Comment: No note that once the installer worked, as I restarted and ubuntu was lunched, but next time again I turned on the machine it prompt me again the free DOS instance as it is not able to find the bootloader(yes I choose the disk as primary from the BIOS)

Comment: Actually I figured out that the problem is that the order in which it was looking for the bootloader has still the SATA as first. Now my ubuntu is loading.

Answer (score 5):

I continually got this error when using the installer's default **Erase disk and install Ubuntu** (with LVM encryption) option, so instead I selected **Something else** to customise my partitions with gparted.

I set a sensible *enough* partition scheme (`60GB primary ext4 /`, `100GB logical ext4 /home`, `10GB swap`) and selected the `primary` partition as the **Device for boot loader installation**, then it installed without the error.

Comment: I owe you a box of doughnuts sir.

Comment: I was able to get an encrypted install of Ubuntu with v16.04 with the bootloader on /dev/nvme0n1 working with UEFI boot

The steps I followed in the installer were:

1) Select manual partition setup
2) make sure drive /dev/nvme0n1 is blank
3) create a partition at front of drive, 1000MB (whatever size you need), mapped to /boot
4) create "physical encrypted partition" following the boot partition with the remaining space
5) assign new encrypted partition with the / mount point
6) select /dev/nvme0n1 as the partition to install the boot loader

Comment: @user1652110 thanks for the comment. Quick question please: where did you find the "physical encrypted partition" option? was it in the install wizard? or in gparted? I can't find it. were you live disc installing (aka you launched the installer within a live session?), or just installing? can you share a screenshot of your disk allocation please?

Answer (score 4):

/dev/nvme is not a correct devicename and will never 'read' as sda.
NVMe's are numbered like mmcblk.
/dev/nvme0n1 as devicename and /dev/nvme0n1p1 as first partition.
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 could work if EFI directory can be found
gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVME devices

Answer (score 4):

I have an Intel NUC5i7RYH with a Samsung NVMe SSD and faced the same issue, which I resolved by entering the BIOS settings and disabling "Legacy" boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a cluster of computers. Each computer that had an additional drive with Windows 10 installed had the issue you describe *when not booting the Live Ubuntu Install USB drive in UEFI Mode*.  Each computer I have that only has the one Linux drive did not require UEFI Mode.

**TLDR**: If you have other systems installed on the same computer (even different hard drive) that use UEFI Mode, then ensure that you boot your live USB in UEFI mode.

From [askubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

> Having a PC with UEFI firmware does not mean that you need to install
>   Ubuntu in UEFI mode. What is important is below:
>
> if the other systems (Windows Vista/7/8, GNU/Linux...) of your
>   computer are installed in UEFI mode, then you must install Ubuntu in
>   UEFI mode too. if the other systems (Windows, GNU/Linux...) of your
>   computer are installed in Legacy (not-UEFI) mode, then you must
>   install Ubuntu in Legacy mode too. Eg if your computer is old (<2010),
>   is 32bits, or was sold with a pre-installed Windows XP.
>
> if Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer, then it does
>   not matter whether you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode or not.

*as for your Ubuntu freezing during loading there could be many other reasons that would merit a separate question*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/942021)

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more explicit, this solution did solve the main problem described for me(it does not solve the subsequent problem of freezing as that would merit a separate question).