# Installing Ubuntu 16-04-1 with disk encryption on nvme SSD using 'Something Else'

Tags: live-usb, encryption, nvme

While installing Ubuntu 16-04-1 from USB device on a Thinkpad P50 with SSD drive;
and selecting "Erase disk and install Ubuntu";
and selecting Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security;

it results in this error message:

**"Executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme'failed. This is a fatal error"**

The problem has been experienced by others, but the solutions always seem to involve setting the correct name for the bootloader as /dev/nvme0n1 after using the "Something else" option in the Installation type screen.
See this thread for example: [Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 9550 -- grub-install /dev/nvme failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788052/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-dell-xps-9550-grub-install-dev-nvme-failed)

I don't know how to set the location for the bootloader as /dev/nvme0n1 and still enjoy automatic disk encryption, with swap and whatever else all encrypted and automatically sorted out for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i have the same issue.. but i don't know how to fix.

Comment: Did you follow the link in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/837052/914627 and visit http://www.rationaljava.com/2016/10/dell-xps13-dual-boot-windows-10-with.html ? - It suggests changing to boot AHCI and editing Grub to point to `nvme0n1` instead of `nvme`.