# Installing Ubuntu Gnome on dell xps 13 problems

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gnome, dell

I have tried to install (dual boot) 16.04.3 LTS on the latest dell xps 13 and I have encountered an issue.

I get a similar issue to the following question:
[Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 9550 -- grub-install /dev/nvme failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788052/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-dell-xps-9550-grub-install-dev-nvme-failed)

The only difference is that it fails to install in something like nvme0n1. Because of this Ubuntu is partly installed so I'm not sure what to do. How can I fix this issue and overwrite the partly installed Ubuntu. I don't want to mess with the Something else option before I'm confident I know what to do.

I have changed to ahci mode in the BIOS. I also tried creating a boot option in the BIOS but rather than loading the installer it loaded some sort of dell recovery/system checker thing.

*New to installing linux operating systems.

Comment: Did you update UEFI from Dell & firmware for NVMe drive? Dell XPS 13 9560 install without issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321 & Dell XPS 13 9360 16.04 worked after nvme firmware & BIOS update, 16.10 did not, new rEFInd for NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install

Comment: @oldfred  Where do I check if I need to update UEFI, is it in the boot menu (pressing f12 on boot). btw I have a 9360 with i5-8250 if that makes any difference

Comment: @oldfred my current BIOS version is 2.2.1, I also have 16.04.3

Comment: Extremely new system. Linux & Ubuntu work well with a bit older system as kernel & drivers eventually catch up. Totally different system, but also very new & notice all the changes to kernels & versions he had to do. ASRock Z370M-ITX/ac: Mini-ITX Motherboard With Dual NICs, WiFi, Triple Display For ~$130 USD Oct 2017
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=asrock-z370m-itx&num=1

Comment: @oldfred so are you saying I may have to wait for it to become compatible? I know that my device must be compatible or surely I wouldn't be able to boot into the try it without installing environment

Comment: You can usually install, but may need to start with 17.10 which is not quite released yet. And still may need to update or add new kernel or drivers separately. Have you updated to latest Dell & NVMe drivers? Do not know versions of every system out there. Do not even know mine other that when I decide to check.

Comment: @oldfred I think I have the latest driver versions because I went on the dell driver website which checked for me

Comment: @oldfred are you sure its not just an issue with the grub2 installer?

Comment: It could be, but I have not seen anyone with the very new Intel chips and what new issues they may have other than the Phoronix article which required kernel & driver updates. Does Dell even yet have a Linux version with the new Intel chips and therefore a new Sputnik that has the newer drivers?

Comment: Another Phoronix post use Intel i5-8400 and again 17.10 with even more updates to kernel & drivers. Also says Intel needs boot parameter: i915.alpha_support=1   https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-linux-8400&num=1

Comment: @oldfred I swear something always goes wrong with me installing Linux... guess ill just have to wait for a proper guide

Comment: I build my own system with about 1 year old from release parts. And only have minor issues at most. My last build/install with Skylake just worked. Build took maybe three hours including unpacking. And install took just a few minutes to SSD and a total of about an hour with configuration. I do not like laptops, except where you have to have the portability. They are not ergonomic, usually lower powered than similar generation desktop and have smaller screens.