# Where should I install bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am trying to install ubuntu alongside of windows 10.

Where should I install my bootloader?

I got the error Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme, when I tried to set the "device for boot loader installation"

I already created swap, /, and /home partitions...

Here's a list of my partitions:

`/dev/nvme0n1`
`/dev/nme0n1p1 efi windows boot manager`
`/dev/nvme0n1p2`
`/dev/nvme0n1p3 ntfs`
`/dev/nvme0n1p7 swap`
`/dev/nvme0n1p8 ext4`
`/dev/nvme0n1p9 ext4`

Comment: Select /dev/nvme

Comment: I can't install it on /dev/nvme, I keep getting "fatal error could not install grub" .. my secure boot is off, using AHCI controllers,

Comment: I think that this should help you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/696999/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-nvme

Comment: If this doesn't solve ur problem then tell me by @smitpatil so I can help more : )