# Unable to install Unbuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Windows 11 pre-installed on SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

Installed successfully Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Windows 11 pre-installed on mini computer.
When trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on another mini-computer: same hardware, *Secure Boot* disabled, *Fast Boot* disabled, *Windows Fast Boot* removed, same set up, got the error:

> Unable to install GRUB/dev/nvme0n1
> Failed.

I tried every solution showed on the net, even Boot Repair.
None of them worked.

Comment: Did you try everything here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/696999/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-nvme

Comment: "/dev/nvme0n1": The absence of the letter "p" suggests you are using GRUB BIOS mode which is for old computers. Yet it's "nvme" meaning SSD, which is for new computers. You should check whether your computer is set to boot in the correct mode, and that your GRUB matches that mode

Answer (score 0):

As said, none of the solutions on the net helped solve my problem.
Started with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Try Ubuntu.
Installed Boot Repair from terminal.

Opened Boot Repair

- Made sure I have a tick on partition `/boot/efi` for `/dev/nvme0n1p1` (second tab GRUB Location)
- Went to GRUB Options and ticked "Update GRUB to most recent version".
- Hit apply.

Finally Boot Repair was able to fix GRUB without any problems.

Removed USB stick.

Went to BIOS to move Ubuntu as the first boot OS before Windows Boot manager.
Finally got GRUB menu on start with dual boot options available and got Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS finally working fine.